# Vignette fails to be built by pkgdown

Tags: r, pkgdown

I have a R package that I am trying to setup `pkgdown` for. I'm following the instructions [here](https://pkgdown.r-lib.org/index.html), and am running `build_site()` to generate the docs directory. When running this command, I get the error

```
Quitting from lines 28-29 (Data-Model.Rmd) 
Error : package or namespace load failed for 'dm':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'dm', details:
  call: register_pkgdown_methods()
  error: rlang::is_installed(c("DiagrammeR", "DiagrammeRsvg")) is not TRUE
```

Showing that the build is failing when trying to render one of the vignettes. However, if I just try to knit this vignette in a fresh interactive session, it knits fine.

I have tried including DiagrammeR and DiagrammeRsvg in Depends, Imports, or Suggests, and it still fails with the same error.

Any idea what I can do to fix this? The vignette is located on my github [here](https://github.com/condwanaland/fishdata/blob/master/vignettes/Data-Model.Rmd). I understand this is not the ideal way to share an example, but it can repro'd by cloning the repo and running `pkgdown::build_site()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is fairly informative; it tells you that

```
rlang::is_installed(c("DiagrammeR", "DiagrammeRsvg"))
```

is not `TRUE`. I suspect if you run that line it will in fact return `FALSE`. I installed `DiagrammeRsvg` and the vignette built successfully.

I am not entirely sure why building the vignette with `pkgdown` requires SVG export of your diagrams, but knitting them doesn't. Hopefully that solves the issue, though.

Comment: That's really weird - I swear I had run the install on that, but maybe I did it in a private library. Cheers, much appreciated